# Using Automation Studio to Export a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation, data-export, automationstudio

I am working with a client to try to create an automated subscriber list export process.

Is there a way use Exact Target's Automation Studio to export data from a Data Extension to either FTP or sent as an email attachment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done with an Automation containing a **Data Extract Activity**. Go to Automation Studio and create a new automation. Add a new *Data Extract Activity*, choose a name, a file naming pattern for your created csv-file and select *Data Extension Extract* as Extract Type. Finally enter the external key of the data extension you like to export.

**Documentation articles:**

- [Data Extract Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/)
- [Create a Data Extract File](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/create_a_data_extract_file/)

Comment: Also note this will need a file transfer activity to move it out of the sandbox onto FTP after extract.

Comment: That depends on the way the data should be used. From the question I assumed it will be manually used and therefore the export folder is suitable. If further processing should be done in Marketing Cloud the file transfer activity will be necessary to move the file to the import folder.