# Export a data extention to FTP using automation?

Tags: ftp, data-extract, marketing-cloud

I searched around for this and found a thread [Using Automation Studio to Export a Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187170/using-automation-studio-to-export-a-data-extension)

But it did not really answer my question. I have a data extension that is created and an automation that runs an SQL query that the puts data view data into this data extention.

I am trying to then export this DE to FTP and I am using a data extract activity, but where do I select this already-named file to export? I thought the external key refers to the data extension you want to use, but I think the external key is randomly generated for this specific data extract activity.  I plugged in the extension I want to use and it errored out.

Where do I select the data extension I want to export into FTP?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Data Extract and File Transfer activities to export a Data Extension:

**Data Extract configuration:** The External Key field can be empty as it refers to the Data Extract activity itself. It is in the second step 'Configuration' where you have to put the external key of the Data Extension you want to export (in the DECustomer Key field).

**File Transfer configuration:** Same logic than the previous activity. Remember that the File Naming Pattern has to be exactly the same that the one you put in the Data Extract. And select in which folder of the FTP the file has to be exported.

Comment: Thanks very helpful, hope this works - they should really put DEcustomerKey as the DE you want to use, like maybe a hover question mark to say what its about.

Comment: Aside from that, when these ftp exports are made, is a new file generated everytime? (I assume it is given that a month day and hour are generated), but does the export start from the BEGINNING or does it insert a new file where the last file  left off?

Comment: If the naming pattern is the same it will overwrite the existing file but if you add the dates it will generate a new one each time.

Comment: I have it as this %%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%%%Hour%%%%Minute%%_DataViewComplaintGCP.csv

So this will generate a new file everytime?  Because the SQL query I have as "append" instead of overwrite, so I believe that only new dates will be added?

Comment: With that naming pattern you will generate a new file each time but the 'Append' applies to the way the DataExtension is updated, nothing about the FTP